# numpy.where for 2+ specific values

Tags: python, numpy

Can the numpy.where function be used for more than one specific value?

I can specify a specific value:

```
>>> x = numpy.arange(5)
>>> numpy.where(x == 2)[0][0]
2
```

But I would like to do something like the following. It gives an error of course.

```
>>> numpy.where(x in [3,4])[0][0]
[3,4]
```

Is there a way to do this without iterating through the list and combining the resulting arrays?

**EDIT:** I also have a lists of lists of unknown lengths and unknown values so I cannot easily form the parameters of np.where() to search for multiple items. It would be much easier to pass a list.

Comment: do you mean [3,4] in x? either way, your array doesn't have a 4 in it.

Comment: Oops, changing the values, thanks @Andrew

Comment: This has a simpler condition than the link.  np.in1d does not apply there.

Comment: @hpaulj I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mind elaborating?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `numpy.in1d` function with `numpy.where`:

```
import numpy
numpy.where(numpy.in1d(x, [2,3]))
# (array([2, 3]),)
```

Comment: Internally, `in1d` is doing the equivalent of `np.where((x==3)|(x==4))`.

Comment: @hpaulj: Is `in1d` faster than `np.where((x==3)|(x==4))`?

Comment: `in1d` is not compiled, so it isn't going to be faster than the comparable action that you write yourself.  It takes a different approach depending on the relative size of the 2 inputs.  It may be easier to use, but not faster.

Answer (score 3):

I guess `np.in1d` might help you, instead:

```
>>> x = np.arange(5)
>>> np.in1d(x, [3,4])
array([False, False, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
>>> np.argwhere(_)
array([[3],
       [4]])
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to check for a few values you can:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(4)

ret_arr = np.where([x == 1, x == 2, x == 4, x == 0])[1]
print "Ret arr = ",ret_arr
```

Output:

```
Ret arr =  [1 2 0]
```